# Moving objects along array?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm sure I must be missing something quite simple - but how do I 'slide' an array along the curve it is following to reposition the array?

The below image is what I'm working on - an array of three pouches, arranged around an oval curve (the curve itself is the profile of a belt). What I want to do is slide the array around the curve to position the pouches further around the torso (roughly the same way you would slide a vertex along an edge). Naturally, I want them to follow the curve because they need to appear as though they are attached to the belt.

[image]

For clarity, I can't just increase the count and delete the spares, because I'd like a finer degree of control over where the pouches are. I also can't rotate the array, as the oval shape means the pouches would begin to float or clip into the torso.

Bit of a complex question - any ideas anyone?

Comment: if you move the object on X or Y, doesn't it give what you want?

Comment: Dude, you got it in one - I knew I was missing something simple. I'm such a dummy. See answer for my explanation :D

Comment: ok, good then.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Answering this myself, because I realised I'm dumb.

The above array was made by parenting (Ctrl+P) the pouch shape to a 2D plane (to avoid the deformation that usually occurs with arrays). It's the plane that controls the array position, not the 3D pouch.

I've been trying to move the 3D shape to relocate the pouches - not the 2D plane. So anyone searching this topic - make sure you're moving the parent object, not the child object!

Thanks to user moonboots, who basically solved this for me in one swoop :D